# Error while extracting data from XML in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle10g, xquery, xmltable

I am using oracle 10g and the query below results in following error:

```
ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence
```

How can we extract all elements in case of multiple items in XML ?
Basically I am interested to separate all underlier instrument wise.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM xmltable(
                xmlnamespaces ('http://www.cool.com/totem/1.1' AS  "n1"), '/n1:totem/n1:results' 
                PASSING xmltype.createxml(('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
            <totem xmlns="http://www.cool.com/totem/1.1">
                <results>
                    <valuationDate>2014-07-31</valuationDate>
                    <clientID>220</clientID>
                    <energy>
                        <underlier>
                            <name>CO2 CER</name>
                            <group>European Emissions</group>
                            <units>EUR / MT</units>
                            <pricingTime>LDN 17:00</pricingTime>
                            <instrument>
                                <period>Month</period>
                                <startDate>2014-12-01</startDate>
                                <endDate>2014-12-31</endDate>
                                <type>Forward</type>
                                <price>0.25852</price>
                                <priceOut>r</priceOut>
                                <contributors>15</contributors>
                            </instrument>
                        </underlier>
                        <underlier>
                            <name>CO2 CER SPOT</name>
                            <group>European Emissions</group>
                            <units>EUR / MT</units>
                            <pricingTime>LDN 17:00</pricingTime>
                            <instrument>
                                <period>Month</period>
                                <startDate>2014-07-31</startDate>
                                <endDate>2014-07-31</endDate>
                                <type>Spot</type>
                                <price>0.17</price>
                                <consensusPrice>0.165988</consensusPrice>
                                <compositePrice>0.165988</compositePrice>
                                <priceRange>0.01</priceRange>
                                <priceStddev>0.004685</priceStddev>
                                <contributors>10</contributors>
                            </instrument>
                        </underlier>
                        <underlier>
                            <name>CO2 EUA</name>
                            <group>European Emissions</group>
                            <units>EUR / MT</units>
                            <pricingTime>LDN 17:00</pricingTime>
                            <instrument>
                                <period>Month</period>
                                <startDate>2014-12-01</startDate>
                                <endDate>2014-12-31</endDate>
                                <type>Forward</type>
                                <price>6.251277</price>
                                <consensusPrice>6.220854</consensusPrice>
                                <compositePrice>6.220854</compositePrice>
                                <priceOut>*</priceOut>
                                <priceRange>0.044779</priceRange>
                                <priceStddev>0.014507</priceStddev>
                                <contributors>18</contributors>
                            </instrument>
                            <instrument>
                                <period>Month</period>
                                <startDate>2015-12-01</startDate>
                                <endDate>2015-12-31</endDate>
                                <type>Forward</type>
                                <price>6.399921</price>
                                <consensusPrice>6.382712</consensusPrice>
                                <compositePrice>6.382092</compositePrice>
                                <priceOut>s</priceOut>
                                <priceRange>0.05</priceRange>
                                <priceStddev>0.014458</priceStddev>
                                <contributors>18</contributors>
                            </instrument>
                            <instrument>
                                <period>Month</period>
                                <startDate>2016-12-01</startDate>
                                <endDate>2016-12-31</endDate>
                                <type>Forward</type>
                                <price>6.590721</price>
                                <consensusPrice>6.563745</consensusPrice>
                                <compositePrice>6.563749</compositePrice>
                                <priceOut>s</priceOut>
                                <priceRange>0.070721</priceRange>
                                <priceStddev>0.017205</priceStddev>
                                <contributors>18</contributors>
                            </instrument>
                        </underlier>
                        <underlier>
                            <name>CO2 EUA SPOT</name>
                            <group>European Emissions</group>
                            <units>EUR / MT</units>
                            <pricingTime>LDN 17:00</pricingTime>
                            <instrument>
                                <period>Month</period>
                                <startDate>2014-07-31</startDate>
                                <endDate>2014-07-31</endDate>
                                <type>Spot</type>
                                <price>6.19</price>
                                <consensusPrice>6.186412</consensusPrice>
                                <compositePrice>6.186412</compositePrice>
                                <priceRange>0.0113</priceRange>
                                <priceStddev>0.004984</priceStddev>
                                <contributors>10</contributors>
                            </instrument>
                        </underlier>
                    </energy>
                </results>
            </totem>'
                                            ))
                COLUMNS     valuationDate        varchar2(500)          PATH 'n1:valuationDate', 
                clientID             varchar2(500)          PATH 'n1:clientID', 
                name                 varchar2(500)          PATH 'n1:energy/n1:underlier/n1:name',
                group1               varchar2(500)          PATH 'n1:energy/n1:underlier/n1:group',
                units                varchar2(500)          PATH 'n1:energy/n1:underlier/n1:units',
                pricingTime          varchar2(500)          PATH 'n1:energy/n1:underlier/n1:pricingTime',   
                period               varchar2(500)          PATH 'n1:energy/n1:underlier/n1:instrument/n1:period',  
                startDate            varchar2(500)          PATH 'n1:energy/n1:underlier/n1:instrument/n1:startDate',  
                endDate              varchar2(500)          PATH 'n1:energy/n1:underlier/n1:instrument/n1:endDate',
                type                 varchar2(500)          PATH 'n1:energy/n1:underlier/n1:instrument/n1:type',
                price                varchar2(500)          PATH 'n1:energy/n1:underlier/n1:instrument/n1:price',
                priceOut             varchar2(500)          PATH 'n1:energy/n1:underlier/n1:instrument/n1:priceOut',
                contributors         varchar2(500)          PATH 'n1:energy/n1:underlier/n1:instrument/n1:contributors'
   ) AS instrument ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your xml, the data is at multiple levels. There are multiple `underlier` tags and each can have more than one `instrument` tags. So, you should break it down in stages.
(Your XML was too long for varchar datatype, so I shortened it.)

*Query:*

```
SELECT 
    tab1.valuationDate, 
    tab1.clientid, 
    tab2.name, 
    tab2.group1,
    tab2.units, 
    tab2.pricingtime,
    tab3.period,        
    tab3.startdate, 
    tab3.enddate,       
    tab3.type,      
    tab3.price,     
    tab3.priceout,  
    tab3.contributors   
FROM
    XMLTABLE(
    xmlnamespaces ('http://www.cool.com/totem/1.1' AS  "n1"), '/n1:totem/n1:results' 
    passing XMLTYPE(
               '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
                    <totem xmlns="http://www.cool.com/totem/1.1">
                        <results>
                            <valuationDate>2014-07-31</valuationDate>
                            <clientID>220</clientID>
                            <energy>
                                <underlier>
                                    <name>CO2 CER</name>
                                    <group>European Emissions</group>
                                    <units>EUR / MT</units>
                                    <pricingTime>LDN 17:00</pricingTime>
                                    <instrument>
                                        <period>Month</period>
                                        <startDate>2014-12-01</startDate>
                                        <endDate>2014-12-31</endDate>
                                        <type>Forward</type>
                                        <price>0.25852</price>
                                        <priceOut>r</priceOut>
                                        <contributors>15</contributors>
                                    </instrument>
                                </underlier>
                                <underlier>
                                    <name>CO2 EUA</name>
                                    <group>European Emissions</group>
                                    <units>EUR / MT</units>
                                    <pricingTime>LDN 17:00</pricingTime>
                                    <instrument>
                                        <period>Month</period>
                                        <startDate>2014-12-01</startDate>
                                        <endDate>2014-12-31</endDate>
                                        <type>Forward</type>
                                        <price>6.251277</price>
                                        <consensusPrice>6.220854</consensusPrice>
                                        <compositePrice>6.220854</compositePrice>
                                        <priceOut>*</priceOut>
                                        <priceRange>0.044779</priceRange>
                                        <priceStddev>0.014507</priceStddev>
                                        <contributors>18</contributors>
                                    </instrument>
                                    <instrument>
                                        <period>Month</period>
                                        <startDate>2015-12-01</startDate>
                                        <endDate>2015-12-31</endDate>
                                        <type>Forward</type>
                                        <price>6.399921</price>
                                        <consensusPrice>6.382712</consensusPrice>
                                        <compositePrice>6.382092</compositePrice>
                                        <priceOut>s</priceOut>
                                        <priceRange>0.05</priceRange>
                                        <priceStddev>0.014458</priceStddev>
                                        <contributors>18</contributors>
                                    </instrument>
                                </underlier>
                        </energy>
                        </results>
                    </totem>'
                    )
    COLUMNS
            valuationDate   VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    'n1:valuationDate',
            clientid    VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    'n1:clientID',
            underlier   XMLTYPE     PATH    'n1:energy/n1:underlier'
            ) tab1,
    XMLTABLE(
        xmlnamespaces ('http://www.cool.com/totem/1.1' AS  "n1"), '/n1:underlier' 
        passing tab1.underlier
    COLUMNS
            name        VARCHAR2(20)    PATH    'n1:name',
            group1      VARCHAR2(30)    PATH    'n1:group',
            units       VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    'n1:units',
            pricingtime VARCHAR2(20)    PATH    'n1:pricingTime',
            instrument  XMLTYPE     PATH    'n1:instrument'
        ) tab2,
    XMLTABLE(
        xmlnamespaces ('http://www.cool.com/totem/1.1' AS  "n1"), '/n1:instrument' 
        passing tab2.instrument
    COLUMNS 
            period      VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    'n1:period',
            startdate   VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    'n1:startDate',
            enddate     VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    'n1:endDate',
            type        VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    'n1:type',
            price       NUMBER      PATH    'n1:price',
            priceout    VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    'n1:priceOut',
            contributors    VARCHAR2(12)    PATH    'n1:contributors'
        ) tab3;
```

*Result:*

```
VALUATIOND CLIENTID   NAME                 GROUP1                         UNITS      PRICINGTIME          PERIOD     STARTDATE  ENDDATE    TYPE            PRICE PRICEOUT   CONTRIBUTORS
---------- ---------- -------------------- ------------------------------ ---------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------
2014-07-31 220        CO2 CER              European Emissions             EUR / MT   LDN 17:00            Month      2014-12-01 2014-12-31 Forward        .25852 r          15
2014-07-31 220        CO2 EUA              European Emissions             EUR / MT   LDN 17:00            Month      2014-12-01 2014-12-31 Forward      6.251277 *          18
2014-07-31 220        CO2 EUA              European Emissions             EUR / MT   LDN 17:00            Month      2015-12-01 2015-12-31 Forward      6.399921 s          18
```